# Using the services that registered in module at the shell viewmodel at the initialize time (WPF, Prism)

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm trying to using prism to build my application, and I faced an exception but I have no idea to solve this.

In the app.xaml.cs file, I override `CreateShell()` method to create the shell used as place holder.

```cs
public partial class App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainView>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainView, MainViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<ServiceModule>();
    }
}
```

And in the Service Module, I register the logging service in the container.

```cs
    public class ServiceModule : IModule
    {
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {

        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();
        }
    }
```

And I want to use the Logger in the `MainViewModel` class, so I injected the `ILoggingService` Service in the `MainViewModel` constructor.

```cs
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly ILoggingService _logger;

        public MainViewModel(ILoggingService logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
    }
```

But here is the happen, when I try to run this code, they throw an exception because the public constructor for `ILoggingService` is not determined.
And I saw the prism project code that initiailize App class what they define in `PrismApplicationBase` class, I finally got one simple question.

```cs
        public virtual void Initialize()
        {
            // ...... Initialize somthing else.......

            var shell = CreateShell();
            if (shell != null)
            {
                RegionManager.SetRegionManager(shell, _containerExtension.Resolve<IRegionManager>());
                RegionManager.UpdateRegions();
                InitializeShell(shell);
            }

            InitializeModules();
        }
```

At the calling CreateShell() time, the modules' aren't initialized yet.

I suspected this routine was wrong at the first time, 
but I found one comment on github that explain why this process is right by code owner. [See on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IXyg.png)

> If CreateShell was last then you would not be able to inject views from within your modules, which would be a massive break and limitation. (brianlagunas)

According to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IXyg.png)
in prism document, The module can be used as a service. So I believe this is not the pattern that prism developers are not recommended.

So here is the question,
What should I do if I want to use my service(`ILoggingService`) in the place holder View Model? (`MainViewModel`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do if I want to use my service (`ILoggingService`) in the shell view model? (`MainViewModel`)

You have to register it from the bootstrapper's `ConfigureContainer`. Or the respective method of your `PrismApplication` child class.

Comment: `ILoggingService` is the service that need to declare in the Service Module. So you mean it is impossible to use `ILoggingService` without registering in the app class directly?
I want to use the `LoggingService` but want to register the services in the `ServiceModule`, not app class directly.

Comment: You could replace the initialization logic (`Bootstrapper.Run`), of course, so that some modules get initialized before the shell, some after, but I doubt it's worth it in the end. Just define the logger in the main app, and be done. If you need another logger, defined later and/or optionally in a module, create another interface. Or create a facade, registered in the shell, that buffers log messages until the module registers the true logger...

Comment: I should probably follow your suggestion... thanks a lot for your comment and opinion